# Can’t get 100% happiness, it's stuck at 99% and EA support doesn’t know either

Tags: paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory

I am currently level 25 and all my buildings are maxed construction, they are all covered by parks and population booster buildings, they have plenty of everything and I’ve followed everything they’ve asked in the small chat bubbles to a T, but for some reason my happiness level will only stay at 99%, it's been like this for months. I’ve tried everything and the support EA has no idea either… Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

Comment: Is it possible this works as intended? I mean, it's kinda philosophical to never reach 100% happiness for a game called in that way.